# How can i make table cells having same width?

Tags: tables

I want to make a table where all the cells will have equal width.[image]

Here the cells width of automobile is bigger than the others.So i want to take all the cells have the width of automobile. I tried this code but don't know how to specify width and height of a cell:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer \\ \hline
airplane   &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
automobile &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
bird       &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
cat        &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Either use `tabularx` package and the `X` column or replace `l` with `p{3cm}` or something like that

Comment: can u show me an example??

Comment: The vertical lines are not really nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way is using the `X` columntype from `tabularx` package  -- it calculates the column width from the width speficied as 1st argument to `tabularx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{p{1.5cm}|}}
\hline
labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer \\ \hline
airplane   &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
automobile &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
bird       &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
cat        &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-other-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{6}{X|}}
\hline
labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer \\ \hline
airplane   &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
automobile &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
bird       &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
cat        &          &            &      &     &      \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. why am i getting this error??

Comment: @setubasak: You have too much `&` in your example. My posted code works

Comment: I have 10x10 table.. yes i have lot of & this.. so what can i do then??

Comment: Replace the `6` from my code with a `10` then ;-) What do you think the `6` does there? ;-)

Comment: how can i control the height of the cell??

Comment: @setubasak: That's not in your question above -- you asked about equal width columns !!! You can't add one request by another one!

Comment: I want to know the details of using tabular parameters??

Comment: @setubasak: Read a book on LaTeX then -- it's quite elementary to use `*{6}{l}` etc. settings.

Answer (score 2):

A nicer-looking version using `booktabs`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-other-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{5}{X}}
\toprule
labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer \\ \midrule
airplane   &          &            &      &     &      \\ 
automobile &          &            &      &     &      \\ 
bird       &          &            &      &     &      \\ 
cat        &          &            &      &     &      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how can i increase or decrease overall table size as my table will be 10x10??

Comment: @setubasak  - You can rotate your table by 90 degrees using the `sidewaystable` environment after loading the `rotating` package.

Comment: @AboAmmar If I need to centralize one column, what should be the structure of \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{5}{X}}?

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `columns-with` to fix the width of all the columns. With the value `auto`, all the columns will have a width equal to the width of the widest cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{NiceTabular}{llllll}[hvlines,columns-width=auto]
labels     & airplane & automobile & bird & cat & deer \\ 
airplane   &          &            &      &     &      \\ 
automobile &          &            &      &     &      \\ 
bird       &          &            &      &     &      \\ 
cat        &          &            &      &     &      \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]